PettingZoo observations and steps with with masked actions for multiple agents of the same type
I've been following a PettingZoo tutorial in order to create this custom environment for a two-player game consisting of a prisoner, trying to escape, and a guard, trying to catch the prisoner. All played on a 7x7 grid, where:

The prisoner starts in the top left corner,

The guard starts in the bottom right corner,

The escape door is randomly placed in the middle of the grid

Both the prisoner and the guard can move in any of the four cardinal directions (up, down, left, right).


import functools
import random
from copy import copy

import numpy as np
from gymnasium.spaces import Discrete, MultiDiscrete

from pettingzoo import ParallelEnv


class CustomActionMaskedEnvironment(ParallelEnv):
    """The metadata holds environment constants.

    The "name" metadata allows the environment to be pretty printed.
    """

    metadata = {
        "name": "custom_environment_v0",
    }

    def __init__(self):
        """The init method takes in environment arguments.

        Should define the following attributes:
        - escape x and y coordinates
        - guard x and y coordinates
        - prisoner x and y coordinates
        - timestamp
        - possible_agents

        Note: as of v1.18.1, the action_spaces and observation_spaces attributes are deprecated.
        Spaces should be defined in the action_space() and observation_space() methods.
        If these methods are not overridden, spaces will be inferred from self.observation_spaces/action_spaces, raising a warning.

        These attributes should not be changed after initialization.
        """
        self.escape_y = None
        self.escape_x = None
        self.guard_y = None
        self.guard_x = None
        self.prisoner_y = None
        self.prisoner_x = None
        self.timestep = None
        self.possible_agents = ["prisoner", "guard"]

    def reset(self, seed=None, options=None):
        """Reset set the environment to a starting point.

        It needs to initialize the following attributes:
        - agents
        - timestamp
        - prisoner x and y coordinates
        - guard x and y coordinates
        - escape x and y coordinates
        - observation
        - infos

        And must set up the environment so that render(), step(), and observe() can be called without issues.
        """
        self.agents = copy(self.possible_agents)
        self.timestep = 0

        self.prisoner_x = 0
        self.prisoner_y = 0

        self.guard_x = 7
        self.guard_y = 7

        self.escape_x = random.randint(2, 5)
        self.escape_y = random.randint(2, 5)

        observation = (
            self.prisoner_x + 7 * self.prisoner_y,
            self.guard_x + 7 * self.guard_y,
            self.escape_x + 7 * self.escape_y,
        )
        observations = {
            "prisoner": {"observation": observation, "action_mask": [0, 1, 1, 0]},
            "guard": {"observation": observation, "action_mask": [1, 0, 0, 1]},
        }

        # Get dummy infos. Necessary for proper parallel_to_aec conversion
        infos = {a: {} for a in self.agents}

        return observations, infos

    def step(self, actions):
        """Takes in an action for the current agent (specified by agent_selection).

        Needs to update:
        - prisoner x and y coordinates
        - guard x and y coordinates
        - terminations
        - truncations
        - rewards
        - timestamp
        - infos

        And any internal state used by observe() or render()
        """
        # Execute actions
        prisoner_action = actions["prisoner"]
        guard_action = actions["guard"]

        if prisoner_action == 0 and self.prisoner_x > 0:
            self.prisoner_x -= 1
        elif prisoner_action == 1 and self.prisoner_x < 6:
            self.prisoner_x += 1
        elif prisoner_action == 2 and self.prisoner_y > 0:
            self.prisoner_y -= 1
        elif prisoner_action == 3 and self.prisoner_y < 6:
            self.prisoner_y += 1

        if guard_action == 0 and self.guard_x > 0:
            self.guard_x -= 1
        elif guard_action == 1 and self.guard_x < 6:
            self.guard_x += 1
        elif guard_action == 2 and self.guard_y > 0:
            self.guard_y -= 1
        elif guard_action == 3 and self.guard_y < 6:
            self.guard_y += 1

        # Generate action masks
        prisoner_action_mask = np.ones(4, dtype=np.int8)
        if self.prisoner_x == 0:
            prisoner_action_mask[0] = 0  # Block left movement
        elif self.prisoner_x == 6:
            prisoner_action_mask[1] = 0  # Block right movement
        if self.prisoner_y == 0:
            prisoner_action_mask[2] = 0  # Block down movement
        elif self.prisoner_y == 6:
            prisoner_action_mask[3] = 0  # Block up movement

        guard_action_mask = np.ones(4, dtype=np.int8)
        if self.guard_x == 0:
            guard_action_mask[0] = 0
        elif self.guard_x == 6:
            guard_action_mask[1] = 0
        if self.guard_y == 0:
            guard_action_mask[2] = 0
        elif self.guard_y == 6:
            guard_action_mask[3] = 0

        # Action mask to prevent guard from going over escape cell
        if self.guard_x - 1 == self.escape_x:
            guard_action_mask[0] = 0
        elif self.guard_x + 1 == self.escape_x:
            guard_action_mask[1] = 0
        if self.guard_y - 1 == self.escape_y:
            guard_action_mask[2] = 0
        elif self.guard_y + 1 == self.escape_y:
            guard_action_mask[3] = 0

        # Check termination conditions
        terminations = {a: False for a in self.agents}
        rewards = {a: 0 for a in self.agents}
        if self.prisoner_x == self.guard_x and self.prisoner_y == self.guard_y:
            rewards = {"prisoner": -1, "guard": 1}
            terminations = {a: True for a in self.agents}
            self.agents = []

        elif self.prisoner_x == self.escape_x and self.prisoner_y == self.escape_y:
            rewards = {"prisoner": 1, "guard": -1}
            terminations = {a: True for a in self.agents}
            self.agents = []

        # Check truncation conditions (overwrites termination conditions)
        truncations = {"prisoner": False, "guard": False}
        if self.timestep > 100:
            rewards = {"prisoner": 0, "guard": 0}
            truncations = {"prisoner": True, "guard": True}
            self.agents = []
        self.timestep += 1

        # Get observations
        observation = (
            self.prisoner_x + 7 * self.prisoner_y,
            self.guard_x + 7 * self.guard_y,
            self.escape_x + 7 * self.escape_y,
        )
        observations = {
            "prisoner": {
                "observation": observation,
                "action_mask": prisoner_action_mask,
            },
            "guard": {"observation": observation, "action_mask": guard_action_mask},
        }

        # Get dummy infos (not used in this example)
        infos = {"prisoner": {}, "guard": {}}

        return observations, rewards, terminations, truncations, infos

    def render(self):
        """Renders the environment."""
        grid = np.zeros((7, 7))
        grid[self.prisoner_y, self.prisoner_x] = "P"
        grid[self.guard_y, self.guard_x] = "G"
        grid[self.escape_y, self.escape_x] = "E"
        print(f"{grid} \n")

    # Observation space should be defined here.
    # lru_cache allows observation and action spaces to be memoized, reducing clock cycles required to get each agent's space.
    # If your spaces change over time, remove this line (disable caching).
    @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    def observation_space(self, agent):
        # gymnasium spaces are defined and documented here: https://gymnasium.farama.org/api/spaces/
        return MultiDiscrete([7 * 7 - 1] * 3)

    # Action space should be defined here.
    # If your spaces change over time, remove this line (disable caching).
    @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    def action_space(self, agent):
        return Discrete(4)

This tutorial shows how to mask illegal actions and therefore limit the action space of an agent. It is done by returning an observation with  Nevertheless, it only features a single agent for each type (prisoner/guard).
I'd now like to expand the environment by adding multiple prisoner agents. I want to assume that each prisoner agent has its own custom action mask (for example to make collisions with other prisoners impossible). Apart from that, they should be able to share a global observation for now, allowing each agent to observe all attributes of each of the other agents.
I looked at some of the generic environments involving multiple agents of one type like the pistonball environment(https://github.com/Farama-Foundation/PettingZoo/blob/master/pettingzoo/butterfly/pistonball/pistonball.py). This environment uses the util.AgentSelector to manage multiple agents of the same type, but I don't quite get how it works. How does the environment keep track of which action to perform by which agent? Also, in the step function, no loop is used to iterate over all agents. How is this managed in the background?
It would be great if someone could explain the usage based on my use case (expanding the env up top).
